# Await query Realtime Updates and then return value [Vuex ,Firestore]

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I’m trying to wait the data from a Firestore real time query, and then perform other actions..
Everything works as expected and I do have the data form firebase as Object, but when I’ve tried to get the proprieties from the returned Object I have an empty result

**Vuex Action**

```
export const getThreadMembers = async ({ commit,dispatch }, payload) => {
      try {
        let members = {}
        const threadMembersRef = await db.collection('members')
                                  .doc(payload.threadId)

        threadMembersRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
          Object.assign(members,doc.data())
        })   
        /*
         * I've tried to add some delay before resolve the promise , i've succeeded to have the properties names of member Object
         *await dispatch('delay', 5000);
         */
        return Promise.resolve(members)
      } catch (error) {
        return  Promise.reject(error)
      }
    }
/*
 * this is a function for test purpose only
 */ 
export const delay = ({commit}) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(42); // After 3 seconds, resolve the promise with value 42
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

**Component file**

```
      created () {
        this.getThreadMembers({
          threadId: this.threadId
        }).then(members => {
          // Here the Members value is an object
          //{bUNFP8ylLpSvZVdIUyOypQ9WfMB3: truej9R1VgexbZU2yp5q5icnIcIg5xB3: true__proto__: Object}
          console.log(members)
          // When i've tried to get only the key of members Object is always empty !?
          console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(members))
         //[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

        })
      }
```

**Question:**

Why `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(members)` is executed before `members` ?

Answer (score 2):

The work of `onSnapshot` is asynchronous, but right now it's not being handled, so the rest of the function just continues without waiting for that promise to resolve. Using `await` is one way to solve this problem.

```
    const doc = await threadMembersRef.onSnapshot()
    Object.assign(members,doc.data())
```

Also you don't need to use `await` on `threadMembersRef` because it's just assigning a reference, not doing any work.

```
const threadMembersRef = db.collection('members')
                              .doc(payload.threadId)
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome explanation, i've tried but i have this error in my console please see in this picture https://imgur.com/a/nrDg2,  i use  "firebase": "^4.9.0",

Comment: i solved this problem by wrapping my function with a Promise Object ,  `export const getThreadMembers = ({ commit,dispatch }, payload) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    let members = {}
    const threadMembersRef = db.collection('members')
                              .doc(payload.threadId)

    threadMembersRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      Object.assign(members,doc.data())
      resolve(members)
    })   
  })    
}`